# Sqlite Provider in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sqlite

I want to use Sqlite Provider which has Linq with Entity Framework feature. But i could not find Sqlite installer which is compatible with VS 2012. I tried to install it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/ but it doesnt get intergrated with VS 2012. I installed SQLite for Windows Runtime too. But that also didnt help. I am not able to find provider while creating ADO.net entity model. Please let me know is there any Sqlite provider available for VS 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx